# Beego: How to parse object url parameters?

Tags: go, datatables, beego

The URL I am receiving looks like this:

```
/controller/action?columns[0][data]=foo&columns[1][data]=bar&columns[2][data]=bar&columns[3][data]=bar&columns[4][data]=bar
```

So I have an array of objects. How can I parse this into a slice of structs?

What I have in my controller action is this:

```
func (this *MyController) Foo() {

  type column struct{
    Data string
  }

  columns := []column{}

  if err := this.Ctx.Input.Bind(&columns, "columns"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  } else {
    log.Println("OK, got:", columns)
  }

}
```

And the output of this is:

```
OK, got: [{} {} {} {} {} {}]
```

Bind successfully detects there are five columns but fails to map the `data` field. I experimented with this and believe there are two problems:

The bind seems to only support the exact syntax shown in the [documentation](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md#data-bind):

```
?id=123&isok=true&ft=1.2&ol[0]=1&ol[1]=2&ul[]=str&ul[]=array&user.Name=astaxie
```

`user.Name=astaxie` works while `user[Name]=astaxie` does not.

The 2nd problem is, the lower case of `data`. My experiments have shown `user.Name` works while `user.name` does not.

So the data bind method expects me to get the parameters in the form `columns[0].Data=foo` while I have `columns[0][data]=foo`

The first one indeed works. But I have no control over the URL, I have to accept it as it is, with lower case `data` in square brackets. The request is generated by [DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

Comment: have you tried to provide a intermediate variable of the type `[]interface{}` instead of `[]column{}` and parse it yourself afterwards? or maybe even just `interface{}`?

Comment: maybe also try `[]map[string]string`. I can imagine that `...[data]=val` is interpreted as a map which would not fit in your column struct.